# Why is AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsHomogenous false

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

It appears that to use the Dynamic keyword my winform .net 4.0 application must have a homogeneous set of security privileges.

If not I receive this error -

Message=Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.

My application has 40+ projects and we have not knowingly set any non-default security settings. ANy pointers as to what to look for and what causes IsHomogenous to be false ?

Tx

Comment: This doesn't sound right, a Winforms app should always run in the primary appdomain which is always homogenous.  If you do create your own appdomains then document that in your question.

Comment: Should not be creating a new AppDomain at least not knowingly. I did a search for AppDomain across all projects and found a few calls to :DefineDynamicAssembly, GetAssemblies, BaseDirectory but no CreateDomain calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to track this down to the fact we had set

legacyCasPolicy enabled="true"

in the app.config file.